# Proving that the intersection of Sylow p-subgroups is normal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

Let $\{K_1, K_2, ..., K_n\}$ be the set of all Sylow $p$-subgroups in a finite group $G$. Prove that $$ H = \cap_{i=1}^{n} K_i $$ is a normal subgroup in G.

**Proof attempt:**

We will proceed by using induction on $n$.

Suppose $n = 1$. 
If there is only one Sylow $p$-subgroup of G, that group must be normal.
So $H = K_1$ is normal.

Assume that the result is true for $n \geq 1$ Sylow $p$-subgroups. Then we want to show it must be true for $n+1$ Sylow $p$-subgroups.

Case 1: There are $n+1$ unique prime factors of $|G|$.
Then each $K_i$ (with $i = 1, ..., n+1$) has a unique prime (or prime-power) order. By uniqueness of prime factorization, then: $$ H = \cap_{i=1}^{n+1} K_i = \{e\} $$ Clearly, this is a normal subgroup.

Case 2: We do not have uniqueness of prime factors.
This is where I get stuck. My idea is that this should fall out from the fact that all Sylow p-subgroups are conjugate with each other, but I'm not exactly sure how to proceed.

Edit: I see the related question, but I'm hoping to receive feedback on my attempt at the solution, and whether this is a possible alternative way to prove the result.

Comment: Edit: See Homework 2 [here](https://www3.nd.edu/~ajorza/courses/2014f-m60210/homework/h05sol.pdf) for another solution, which I think is much shorter than to try induction.